# Packing a set of boxes with a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I was challenged to solve the following problem recursively, but I still can't.

The problem: It is necessary to pack all items from the following set

```
int[] items = new int[] {4, 4, 2, 3};
```

into the following boxes

```
int[] boxes = new int[] {5, 8};
```

At the moment, at the end of the algorithm I have

```
Item index: 2
Box index: 1
Items: 0, 0, 0, 3, 
Boxes: 1, 2, 
-------------------------------------------------
It is possible to distribute defined set of items in given boxes.
```

Which is not correct, because there is an item 3 and there are two boxes with remaining capacity 1 and 2. The final positive result I am getting from the right side of the "||" expression.

Could someone indicate the wrong code or recommend a right solution? Thanks!

My java code is below:

```
public class Boxes
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] items = new int[] {4, 4, 2, 3};
        int[] boxes = new int[] {5, 8};

        System.out.println( String.format("It is %spossible to distribute defined set of items in given boxes.", IsFit(items, boxes, 0, 0) ? "" : "NOT " ) );

    }

    private static boolean IsFit(int[] items, int[] boxes, int boxIndex, int itemIndex)
    {
        if (boxIndex == boxes.length)
            return false;

        if (itemIndex == items.length)
            return true;

        boolean result = 
                IsFit(items, boxes, boxIndex + 1, itemIndex)
                || 
                IsFit(items, boxes, boxIndex, itemIndex + 1) 
            ;   

        if (result)
        {
            int storedValue = items[itemIndex];

            if (boxes[boxIndex] >= storedValue)
            {
                boxes[boxIndex] -= storedValue;
                items[itemIndex] = 0;

                /*
                System.out.println( String.format("Item index: %d", itemIndex) );
                System.out.println( String.format("Box index: %d", boxIndex) );

                System.out.print("Items: ");
                for (int i : items)
                    System.out.print( String.format("%s, ", i) );
                System.out.println();


                System.out.print("Boxes: ");
                for (int b : boxes)
                    System.out.print( String.format("%s, ", b) );
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
                */

                result = IsFit(items, boxes, boxIndex, itemIndex + 1);

                items[itemIndex] = storedValue;
                boxes[boxIndex] += storedValue;

            }
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clearly state what the actual challenge is?

Comment: Is it meant to distribute the items in the boxes so all items and boxes are 0 at the end of the run. Or is it meant to say "It is NOT possible to distribute..." since there is items and box-space still left?

Comment: It is necessery to tell if it is possible to spread all available items into given boxes.

Comment: @you would get more engagement from users if you stated that you are working on a knapsack problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but i double if highligting a Knapsack missleads from the current problem. If I am not mistaken the Knapsack problem deals with a single pack.Single pack algorithm is not a problem to me. I have stacked with a case when there are more than 1 back with the limitted size

Comment: +1 For given a nice logic to think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is pretty hard to follow. I would propose the following function:

```
private static boolean fits(int[] weights, int[] boxes, int i) {
    if (i == weights.length)
        return true;

    for (int j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
        if (weights[i] <= boxes[j]) {
            boxes[j] -= weights[i];
            if (fits(weights, boxes, i+1))
                return true;

            boxes[j] += weights[i];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which should be called as

```
fits(items, boxes, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The final posiive result I am getting from the Rigth side of the "||" expression.

I believe you are mistaken. Your final positive result probably comes from this:

```
if (itemIndex == items.length)
    return true;
```

Of course this does not solve the whole problem. The problem is (from what I can see) a case of the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) and you must solve it using a brute-force algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the rigth part of '||' leads exatly to the expression in case of <Item index: 2>, <Box index: 1>

Answer (score 0):

This challenge has `impressed` me a lot, that's why i am posting my answer though this question was accepted.!

```
  private static boolean CheckTheBox(int[] a,int[] b,int i,int j)
     {           
            i+=(a[i]==0)?1:0;
            j+=(b[j]==0)?1:0;

            if(i > a.length -1 || j > b.length -1)
            {
                return (a[a.length-1]==0 && b[b.length-1]==0)?true:false;
            }

            int temp=a[i];
            a[i]-=(a[i]!=0 && b[j]!=0)?1:0;
            b[j]-=(b[j]!=0 && temp!=0)?1:0;

            CheckTheBox(a,b,i,j);

            return (a[a.length-1]==0 && b[b.length-1]==0)?true:false;
    }
```

Can be called like below,

```
System.out.println((CheckTheBox(items,boxes,0,0)==true?"Filled Successfully.!":"Items/Boxes Remaining.!"));
```